# Is that logical to create new record with oberservers?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a "notification" system, I got some conditions, and when those conditions are triggered, then I will create a notification record to "notifications" table.

For example;
When my product quantity drop below the "critical stock level", It will create new record to "notifications" table.

I will use the code below:

Product.php model:

```
use App\Traits\RecordSignature;
class Product extends Model
{
    use RecordSignature, TrimScalarValues;
    ....
```

RecordSignature.php

```
namespace App\Traits;

use app\Observers\ModelSignature;

trait RecordSignature
{
    
    public static function bootObservantTrait()
    {
        static::observe(new ModelSignature);
    }
}
```

ModelSignature.php

```
namespace App\Observers;

class ModelSignature {

    protected $userID;

    public function __construct($userID){
        $this->userID =  Auth::id();
    }


    public function created($model)
    {
        if($model->critical > $model->quantity){
          $notif = new Notification();
          $notif->message = 'your product is below the critical stock';
          $notif->save();
        }
    }

}
```

Is that the good way to make It happen? (I will make more oberservers for more tables)
Or is there any "better ways" for those condition checks?

Comment: you can use laravel observer class https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers

Comment: actually, I shared the oberserver code above. I made it with observers, but is that way the best way?

Comment: no use laravel built in method